# 'please minimize large stack variables' error on building hello_world

Tags: error

I am trying to run hello_world example and I'm getting this error during building:

```
$ cargo build-bpf
```

> Error: Function
> *ZN112*$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17hb146f131e68574cfE
> Stack offset of 4584 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 488 bytes, please
> minimize large stack variables

I reinstalled cargo and solana cli and still getting this. My files:

Cargo.toml

```
[package]

name = "hello_world"

version = "0.1.0"

edition = "2021"



# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html



[dependencies]

solana-program = "1.18.1"



[lib]

name = "hello_world"

crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

src/lib.rs

```
use solana_program::{

    account_info::AccountInfo,

    entrypoint,

    entrypoint::ProgramResult,

    pubkey::Pubkey,

    msg,

};



entrypoint!(process_instruction);



// program entrypoint's implementation

pub fn process_instruction(

    program_id: &Pubkey,

    accounts: &[AccountInfo],

    instruction_data: &[u8]

) -> ProgramResult {

    // log a message to the blockchain

    msg!("Hello, world!");



    // gracefully exit the program

    Ok(())

}
```

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3

```
$ solana --version

solana-cli 1.18.1 (src:5d824a36; feat:756280933, client:SolanaLabs)
```

```
$ cargo --version

cargo 1.75.0 (1d8b05cdd 2023-11-20)
```

```
$ rustc --version

rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
```

Answer (score 4):

This error class can be ignored if it doesn't cause you any problems. It is sort of a warning rather than a full compile error.

This specific problem from the `InstructionError` was introduced in the `1.18.0` release and is being tracked in https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/35003.